# CodeIgniter Active Record Queries W/ Sub Queries

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

#### Question:

I really am trying to stick to using ActiveRecord and not using straight SQL.. can someone help me convert this to activerecord?

Trying to get the email address and contact name from another table. `map_userfields` table is a one to many, multiple rows per `p.id`. one row per `p.id` per `uf.fieldid`.

#### see this screenshot for a reference to the map_userfields table:

[image]

#### Current Non active record query

```
SELECT
p.id,
(SELECT uf.fieldvalue FROM map_userfields uf WHERE uf.pointid = p.id AND uf.fieldid = 20) As ContactName,
(SELECT uf.fieldvalue FROM map_userfields uf WHERE uf.pointid = p.id AND uf.fieldid = 31) As ContactEmail
FROM
map_points p
WHERE
/** $pointCategory is an array of categories to look for **/
p.type IN($pointCategory)
```

**Note:** I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.x, MySQL 5.x, php 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select anything you need with CI's activeRecords as long as you tell CI not to parse your string

```
$this->db->select('p.id,
(SELECT uf.fieldvalue FROM map_userfields uf WHERE uf.pointid = p.id AND uf.fieldid = 20) As ContactName,
(SELECT uf.fieldvalue FROM map_userfields uf WHERE uf.pointid = p.id AND uf.fieldid = 31) As ContactEmail
',TRUE);
$this->db->from('map_points p');
$this->db->where_in('p.type',$pointCategory);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to avoid this? OR is this considered the best practice available?

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter's Active Record doesn't support subqueries out-of-the-box. You'll need to download the [CodeIgniter Subqueries class](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries).

In the CodeIgniter wiki, there's an [article on how to subqueries](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Subqueries).

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries indeed work in codeigniter but there is a little hack. I found that in in system/database/DB_active_rec.php there are two functions named _compile_select and _reset_select. If you remove the protected word from both you will be able to use these function for subqueries
Here is a usage tutorial

http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/